# Not working Nginx's reverse proxy on new IP

Tags: nginx, debian

I have one site and the configuration for that named **mysite.com**. Config's below.

```
server {

        listen 1.2.3.4:80;
        listen 1.2.3.4:443 default ssl;

        server_name mysite.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard_cert.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard_key.com.key;

        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache off;

        if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 444;
        }

        include include/locations.conf;

}
```

Also, in the file **locations.conf** I have the reverse proxy rules. It's below.

```
location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://mysite-on-IIS;
        }
```

It works fine.

I got the assignment to configure the same non-SSL site. For that I createad a new IP for linux's interface where Nginx installed. See **/etc/network/interfaces** file below.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4
        netmask 255.255.255.240

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 1.2.3.5
        netmask 255.255.255.240
```

And I created a new configuration file named **mysite.ir** (non-SSL, because our provider doesn't support SSL for Iran). The configuration file is the same as mysite.com. I copypasted it and just deleted SSL lines. See it below.

```
server {

        listen 1.2.3.5:80;

        server_name mysite.ir;

        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache off;

        if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 444;
        }

        include include/locations.conf;

}
```

If I go to mysite.com – everything is working.
***If I go to mysite.ir – I see default Nginx greeting instead my site specyfyed in proxy***. Even if I changing IP in mysite.ir file to IP from mysite.com – it's working properly too.
If I go to site by IP from mysite.com or mysite.ir I see default Nginx greeting.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Why would you create a new IP? Nginx can listen for http and https on the same IP, same or different domain name. It can listen on different ones too, of course. Assume Nginx has been restarted? Please edit your question to include curl to new site and corresponding access / error logs.

Comment: Are you sure that Nginx can listen on the same or different domain? I wrote "why" in the first answer with proofs. I encountered with a problem. Nginx put certificate for mysite.com if I force type http**s**://mysite.ir and browser throws me "Connection is not secure" error because certificates names mismatch (.ir and .com).

Comment: Do you have valid certificates installed for both domains?

Comment: I have certificate installed only for one domain named mysite.com (wildcard *.mysite.com). I don't have a certificate for mysite.ir because our provides doesn't support certificates for .ir (Iran) domains. We have all https redirect everywhere except mysite.ir but if I type http**s**://mysite.ir I see the error in browser, click proceed and only then redirect works.

Comment: Re comment above, my server has one IP address and hosts five https sites with their matching http sites. This requires SNI which the very oldest browsers don't support, but the vast majority do. I'll let go that 1% of traffic to reduce the need for scarce IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

How critical is it to be running these sites from two different NICs? I'd suggest just creating one server configuration block for https (include 443 listener and and SSL configuration) and another block for http traffic (port 80, no certs)

Then just forward both to the correct upstream and just set:

```
server {  
  listen 80 default_server;  
  server_name _;  
  add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;  
  proxy_cache off;  
  location / {  
    include proxy_params;  
    if ($allowed_country = no) { return 444; }  
    proxy_pass http://mysite-on-IIS;   
    proxy_set_header Host $host;  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this way initially. But there is one problem. If I go to site without https and specify http**s**://mysite.ir then Nginx add certificate from another site named mysite.com and browser shows me SSL-privacy warning with red background. [More](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#name_based_https_servers) about this.

Comment: Just the copypaste.

_With this configuration a browser receives the default server’s certificate, i.e. www.example.com regardless of the requested server name. This is caused by SSL protocol behaviour. The SSL connection is established before the browser sends an HTTP request and nginx does not know the name of the requested server. Therefore, it may only offer the default server’s certificate._

Comment: Either your nginx or client is ancient. SSL feature called Server Name Indication (SNI) tells nginx which host name is going to be accessed, and therefore nginx can select the correct virtual host. SNI has been implemented for years now.

Comment: For the https copy of your config I would suggest setting server_name to valid value (ie. whatever lines up to your certs. Although, I'm not sure what NGINX will try to do if you access it on a port that is listening for another domain name and it doesn't have any certificate at all for the one requested. I suspect that it would pass whichever certificate it has, but you could also probably open up the NGINX docs on ssl to sort that out.